# Apache NiFi stream into InfluxDB

Tags: apache-nifi, influxdb

Within a cloud application I'm using NiFi (=> I'm a newbee) to work with data streams published by a mqtt broker. So far so good.
In the end I want to stream into an InfluxDB. That's the point I'm struggling with.
Does anybody have some experiences with a processor for such a setup? Is there a suitable processor for writing data into an InfluxDB?

Thanks a lot.

Kind regards,
T_F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [`PutInfluxDB`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-influxdb-nar/1.9.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.influxdb.PutInfluxDB/) processor which accepts the incoming flowfile and writes the content as 'line content' in InfluxDB.